# Is threre is way to specify asterisk directories on install or make astreisk from source?

Tags: asterisk

My asterisk installation (1.8.12.0, mac osx 10.8.2) has these default directories :

```
* Directories
-------------
Configuration file:          
Configuration directory:     /usr/local/etc/asterisk
Module directory:            /Library/Application Support/Asterisk/Modules/modules
Spool directory:             /var/spool/asterisk
Log directory:               /Library/Logs/Asterisk
Run/Sockets directory:       /Library/Application Support/Asterisk/Run
PID file:                    /Library/Application Support/Asterisk/Run/asterisk.pid
VarLib directory:            /Library/Application Support/Asterisk
Data directory:              /Library/Application Support/Asterisk
ASTDB:                       /Library/Application Support/Asterisk/astdb
IAX2 Keys directory:         /Library/Application Support/Asterisk/keys
AGI Scripts directory:       /Library/Application Support/Asterisk/agi-bin
```

But directories section in asterisk.conf is template:

```
[directories](!)
astetcdir => /usr/local/etc/asterisk
astmoddir => /Library/Application Support/Asterisk/Modules/modules
astvarlibdir => /Library/Application Support/Asterisk
astdbdir => /Library/Application Support/Asterisk
astkeydir => /Library/Application Support/Asterisk
astdatadir => /Library/Application Support/Asterisk
astagidir => /Library/Application Support/Asterisk/agi-bin
astspooldir => /var/spool/asterisk
astrundir => /Library/Application Support/Asterisk/Run
astlogdir => /Library/Logs/Asterisk
```

Goal: set directoies default values as it is on Debian/Ubuntu installation:

```
* Directories
-------------
Configuration file:          
Configuration directory:     /etc/asterisk
Module directory:            /usr/lib/asterisk/modules
Spool directory:             /var/spool/asterisk
Log directory:               /var/log/asterisk
Run/Sockets directory:       /var/run/asterisk
PID file:                    /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.pid
VarLib directory:            /var/lib/asterisk
Data directory:              /var/lib/asterisk
ASTDB:                       /var/lib/asterisk/astdb
IAX2 Keys directory:         /var/lib/asterisk/keys
AGI Scripts directory:       /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin
```

Directories in asterisk.conf:

```
[directories]
astetcdir=>/etc/asterisk
astmoddir=>/usr/lib/asterisk/modules
astvarlibdir=>/var/lib/asterisk
astdbdir=>/var/lib/asterisk
astkeydir=>/var/lib/asterisk
astdatadir=>/var/lib/asterisk
astagidir=>/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin
astspooldir=>/var/spool/asterisk
astrundir=>/var/run/asterisk
astlogdir=>/var/log/asterisk
```

How can i set directories settings on install/configure step?

One more thing : i found file, name asterisk.pc located in  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/ :

```
install_prefix=
version_number=999999
etcdir=/usr/local/etc/asterisk
libdir=/Library/Application Support/Asterisk/Modules
varlibdir=/Library/Application Support/Asterisk
varrundir=/Library/Application Support/Asterisk/Run
spooldir=/var/spool/asterisk
logdir=/Library/Logs/Asterisk
confpath=/usr/local/etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf
moddir=/Library/Application Support/Asterisk/Modules/modules
agidir=/Library/Application Support/Asterisk/agi-bin

Name: asterisk
Description: Open Source PBX and telephony toolkit
Version: SVN-branch-1.8-r375325
Libs:
Cflags: -I/usr/include/libxml2-g3 -D__Darwin__
```

What is it? Is this file created after install or configure?

Comment: BTW, make config says :"We could not install init scripts for your operating system."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question : 
To make def. dirs you need to configure asterisk with parameters : --prefix=/ --exec_prefix=/usr

(see parameters mapping https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArO2cmv04QLpdHR0UVZaNzJMR2tKNTFJdjlnSkc2RFE )